# iTunes Connect version control

Tags: ios, version-control, app-store-connect

First of all I want to thank all of you for this great community. I started coding my app in March of this year with zero experience and just yesterday my app was approved for the App Store.

I have a pretty tight release deadline being the first of September so I'm happy that my app is already Ready For Sale. Since my app submission I made some minor changes to the UI and corrected some spelling errors so it's really nothing dramatic but I'd like to update it before release.

So my question is, is there any problem uploading a new version when I haven't released anything so far? I don't want to lose the Ready For Sale approval for my first version, just in case anything would go wrong during the review process.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: You can submit a new version without affecting your first version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can submit your new version of application .It will not affect your current version of application.If application will be approved then old one will be removed from appstore and newer one version will be ready for sell .If New version will not be approved then old version will be ready for sell.

Comment: This is mostly true. However, the old app could be rejected along the new one if the reviewer thought it was convenient, e.g. they hadn't noticed the app didn't have content enough. It mostly depends on the reviewer and a rejection of a previously released app version would be something very uncommon.